# Get duplicates between two lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to get the duplicates between two lists. Something like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,8,4,6]

duplicates = getDuplicates(list1, list2)
print(duplicates)  # =>  = [1,2,4]
```

I tried to search for an answer, but I only found how to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Use a list comprehension. Check if each item in `list1` is in `list2`, if so add it to the list, if not do nothing.

Comment: In your example, the "duplicates" happen to be at the same positions. Is it the only duplicates you want to detect? That is, what if `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are the inputs? Do you expect `[]` as the output, or `[1, 2]`?

Comment: Extending @j1-lee comment, What will happen if list1 contains `[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6]` and list contains `[1,2,2,2,4] `? the result should be `[1,2,2,2,4]` or `[1,2,4]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to get the duplicates.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1, 2, 8, 4, 6]
print (set(list1) & set(list2))
```

This only works for equal sized lists, does implies significance order, or you can do the other way below which does work for unequal sized lists.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1, 2, 8, 4, 6]
print (set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` and the [`.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method. Like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,8,4,6]

duplicates = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
print(duplicates)  # => [1, 2, 4]
```

I tested this against [jsbueno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74365442/13376511) using `timeit` and found that my answer is **significantly faster**. For two lists of 5 elements each, my answer took 0.64 seconds for 1,000,000 runs, while jsbueno's took 0.74 seconds. When scaled up to two lists of 100 elements, my answer took only 4.54 seconds while his answer took 8.08. My takeaway from this is that the built-in `set.intersection` scales much better than a list comprehension.

Comment: I followed yours and it worked perfectly. Thank you all for your quick and effective answers!

Answer (score 0):

By converting one of the lists to a set prior to picking members, this operation will run in linear time - rather than in quadratic time.

That can make a huge difference if both lists start to get to the hundreds of thousands of items:

```
set1 = set(list1)
duplicates = [item for item in list2 if item in set1]
```

otherwise, for just a handful of items, a simple filter is enough:

```
duplicates = [item for item in list2 if item in list1]
```

Comment: What will happen if list1 contains `[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6]` and list contains `[1,2,2,2,4] `? the result should be `[1,2,2,2,4]` or `[1,2,4]`

Comment: this filter is rather straightforward, and , as posted here, it will keep any element on list2 that happens to be on list1, regardless of its position on list1, and repeated as many times as it shows up in list2, in order of appearance there. It is trivial to get other outputs, but one needs to write the code according with the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop, but I think it is slow in bigger arrays. In that case, it should be

```
duplicates = [i for i in list1  if i in list2]
```

or you can use sets

```
set(list1) & set(list2)
```

or you can use the [intersection](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) which is faster.

```
duplicates = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
```